# Joining two Dataframes by index

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes as below and would like to join them to create the resulting third one.

```html
<td>df1</td> 

<table><tbody><tr><th> </th><th>V1</th></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>B</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>B</td><td>4</td></tr></tbody></table>


<td>df2</td> 

<table><tbody><tr><th> </th><th>V2</th></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>6</td></tr><tr><td>B</td><td>7</td></tr><tr><td>B</td><td>8</td></tr></tbody></table>


<td>res</td>
 
<table><tbody><tr><th> </th><th>V1</th><th>V2</th></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>1</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>2</td><td>6</td></tr><tr><td>B</td><td>3</td><td>7</td></tr><tr><td>B</td><td>4</td><td>8</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

For both Dataframes the indexes are Index(['A','A','B','B],dtype='object')

Comment: Please share expected output. And check [`df.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

Comment: Thanks, I tried df.join but it creates repeated values, you can see the expected output if you scroll down

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

For more information: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html